# Why is R function parameter being treated as an object

Tags: r, opencpu

I have written a function in R as follows:

```
    createV <- function(vid){
    vid1 = substring(toString(vid),3)
    return(vid1)
     }
```

I have exposed this function as an api using opencpu

when i call the API where parameter vid = "abcd123",
it throws an error saying object not found in call: substring(abcd123)

It treats the variable content as object.
How do I fix this?

Comment: How do uou call/invoke from your client? To pass strings, (for instance with JSON) it is required to enquote such as: `data:{vid: "'abcd123'"}}` (double quote to respect JSON structre, single quote within to be evaluated as string by R)

Comment: Oh it worked :) Thanks a lot.  I was en quoting it only once using double quote.